# Correlation in Bernoulli trial

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have a large dataset of tennis-points (who served and if they won etc).

Now I would like to check if the points have any correlation with each other (does winning/losing the previous point affect the current or the one after this?).

I also have an "estimate" of each players serve-winning probability as well as his "actual" serve-winning probability in the game (calculated from the dataset).

Ive tried looking into autocorrelation but I honestly dont know where to start. Does anyone have any idea how to test if Point X have any effect on the outcome of Point X+1?

Any help is greatly appreciated

PS. I tried asking a similar question describing how I thought and the only answer I get was "You are lacking fundamental understanding about probability-theory", hence this time I havent included any of my own thought-process, but feel free to ask for more info if I have excluded something important
DS.

Comment: This problem has been well studied, though it is still somewhat controversial.  You can read about it online by looking up [Hot Hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-hand_fallacy) .

Comment: Well lets assume I am not talking about tennis-points but another sequence of 1s and 0s, how would I go about looking for some sort of relationship between the data?

I have looked at a lot of other peoples research but mostly it talks about winning the previous point and not winning the point 2 points ago for example. Nor is it based on actual point by point data but instead on some sort of estimate.

Comment: The coin toss version is the same problem.  You should read the literature on the problem, it is very extensive.  And you should look up the recent paper by [Miller and Sanjuro](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2627354) which reveals a subtle flaw in all the preceding work.  It's not an easy problem.